# Simple experiment to do at home that involves acids and bases?

Tags: acid-base, ph, home-experiment

so long story short I am in the IB Diploma and I am required to come up with an experiment to investigate pretty much anything to do with chemistry. I'm thinking about doing mine on investigating how temperature affects the pH value of a solution, but my teacher said it was too simple.

Basically, is there any reaction I can make at home with simple chemicals(vinegar, baking soda, salt, juice, etc.) that would produce a meaningful experiment and involves me measuring the pH level? Thank you guys so much.

Comment: Maybe mixing boric acid (maybe made from borax) and glycerine or other polyol? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boric_acid Question looks too broad unfortunately.

Comment: There will be no measurable impact on pH at temperatures you can generate at home. How about something like measuring how accurate the percentage of store bought hydrogen peroxide is? Simple titration.

Answer (score 2):

Measure the pH+ of various foods, and make a spreadsheet listing them.

You might also measure pH+ change with time in a food, e.g. apple juice or bread dough, with a few mg of yeast sprinkled in.

Answer (score 1):

How about home made indicators? There are plenty of plant based colorants that can change color on pH change. You can make it easy way ( listing colors in acidic, neutral, basic  solutions) or make it more difficult, eg actually comparing in what pH the color changes (hint: it is generally not exactly pH 7)